# Draw dynamic spider chart with bezier path

Tags: swift, xcode, graph, uibezierpath, spider-chart

[image: Custom spider chart with sections]

You can see the image, I want to draw a custom spider chart like this with different section. This is a dynamic spider chart with dynamic sections, I want to colour different sections based on my api data, How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use UIBezierPath for that. I think the circles are clear. For the differently colored segments, you can use the function `bezierPathWithArcCenter:radius:startAngle:endAngle:clockwise:` (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uibezierpath/1624358-bezierpathwitharccenter) and fill it with the desired color.